# Passing mutable self reference to method of owned object

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The following is a simple simulation with a field which is a rectangular area with two balls bouncing around in it. The `Field` struct has an `update` method, which calls `update` on each of the balls. The balls, in their `update` method, need to move around based on their velocity. But they also need to react to each other, as well as the boundaries of the field.:

```
fn main() {
    let mut field = Field::new(Vector2d { x: 100, y: 100 });
    field.update();
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Vector2d {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

struct Ball {
    radius: i32,
    position: Vector2d,
    velocity: Vector2d,
}

impl Ball {
    fn new(radius: i32, position: Vector2d, velocity: Vector2d) -> Ball {
        Ball {
            radius: radius,
            position: position,
            velocity: velocity,
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, field: &Field) {
        // check collisions with walls
        // and other objects
    }
}

struct Field {
    size: Vector2d,
    balls: [Ball; 2],
}

impl Field {
    fn new(size: Vector2d) -> Field {
        let position_1 = Vector2d {
            x: size.x / 3,
            y: size.y / 3,
        };
        let velocity_1 = Vector2d { x: 1, y: 1 };
        let position_2 = Vector2d {
            x: size.x * 2 / 3,
            y: size.y * 2 / 3,
        };
        let velocity_2 = Vector2d { x: -1, y: -1 };

        let ball_1 = Ball::new(1, position_1, velocity_1);
        let ball_2 = Ball::new(1, position_2, velocity_2);

        Field {
            size: size,
            balls: [ball_1, ball_2],
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self) {
        // this does not compile
        self.balls[0].update(self);
        self.balls[1].update(self);
    }
}
```

How do I get the information about the boundaries and the other ball to the `Ball` struct's update function? These lines in the `Field::update` do not compile:

```
self.balls[0].update(self);
self.balls[1].update(self);
```

Giving the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because `self.balls[..]` is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:62:30
   |
62 |         self.balls[0].update(self);
   |         -------------        ^^^^- mutable borrow ends here
   |         |                    |
   |         |                    immutable borrow occurs here
   |         mutable borrow occurs here
```

which I understand, but I don't know how to get around this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently your `Ball` struct needs to know about the `Field` it's contained in to be able to update itself. This doesn't compile because the result would be cyclic references combined with mutation. You could make this work by using `Cell` or `RefCell` (the latter having a performance cost) but it would be even better to structure the code differently. Let the `Field` struct check for and resolve `Ball`-`Ball` and `Ball`-`Wall` collisions. The `Ball` struct's `update` function can handle updating the `Ball`'s position.

```
// Ball's update function
fn update(&mut self) {
    // update position
}

// Field's update function
fn update(&mut self) {
    for ball in self.balls.iter_mut() {
        ball.update();
    }

    // check for collisions

    // resolve any collisions
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work. Man, Rust is really making me think differently about the way I program.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a smaller example:

```
struct Ball {
    size: u8,
}

impl Ball {
    fn update(&mut self, field: &Field) {}
}

struct Field {
    ball: Ball,
}

impl Field {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        self.ball.update(self)
    }
}
```

## The problem

When you pass in a reference to `Field`, you are making the guarantee that the `Field` cannot change (the *immutable* part of "immutable reference"). However, this code is also attempting to mutate a part of it: the ball! Which reference should be authoritative, `self` or `field`, in the implementation of `Ball::update`?

## Solution: use only the fields you need

You can separate the parts of the structure needed for `update` and those not needed and use them *before* calling the `update` function:

```
struct Ball {
    size: u8,
}

impl Ball {
    fn update(&mut self, field: &u8) {}
}

struct Field {
    players: u8,
    ball: Ball,
}

impl Field {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        self.ball.update(&self.players)
    }
}
```

You can even bundle these piecemeal references up into a tidy package:

```
struct Ball {
    size: u8,
}

impl Ball {
    fn update(&mut self, field: BallUpdateInfo) {}
}

struct BallUpdateInfo<'a> {
    players: &'a u8,
}

struct Field {
    players: u8,
    ball: Ball,
}

impl Field {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        let info = BallUpdateInfo { players: &self.players };
        self.ball.update(info)
    }
}
```

Or restructure your containing struct to separate the information from the beginning:

```
struct Ball {
    size: u8,
}

impl Ball {
    fn update(&mut self, field: &UpdateInfo) {}
}

struct UpdateInfo {
    players: u8,
}

struct Field {
    update_info: UpdateInfo,
    ball: Ball,
}

impl Field {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        self.ball.update(&self.update_info)
    }
}
```

## Solution: remove the member from `self`

You could also go the *other* way and remove the `Ball` from the `Field` before making any changes to it. If you can easily / cheaply make a `Ball`, try replacing it:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Ball {
    size: u8,
}

impl Ball {
    fn update(&mut self, field: &Field) {}
}

struct Field {
    ball: Ball,
}

impl Field {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        let mut ball = mem::replace(&mut self.ball, Ball::default());
        ball.update(self);
        self.ball = ball;
    }
}
```

If you can't easily make a new value, you can use an `Option` and `take` it:

```
struct Ball {
    size: u8,
}

impl Ball {
    fn update(&mut self, field: &Field) {}
}

struct Field {
    ball: Option<Ball>,
}

impl Field {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        if let Some(mut ball) = self.ball.take() {
            ball.update(self);
            self.ball = Some(ball);
        }
    }
}
```

## Solution: runtime checks

You can move borrow checking to runtime instead of compile-time via [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Ball {
    size: u8,
}

impl Ball {
    fn update(&mut self, field: &Field) {}
}

struct Field {
    ball: RefCell<Ball>,
}

impl Field {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        self.ball.borrow_mut().update(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a really extensive and nice answer @Shepmaster. One of the hardest things starting out with Rust might just be to learn these patterns. Beyond the linked list book, I wish there was a resources with solutions like this in one place. It helps you think about the code, and how to shape it within Rust's natural boundaries.